# Possible to pass a data value from a kendoSwitch

Tags: asp.net-core, kendo-ui, switch-statement, telerik

Is it possible to pass a data value from a kendoSwitch?

Simple dojo here:  https://dojo.telerik.com/eCUVitEC/2

Code as follows:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="theSwitch" data-id="MyId" />
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#theSwitch").kendoSwitch({
            change: function (e) {
                alert("checked: " + e.checked);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

This works but what I really want is to pass the data-id, not the checked value.  I have tried a number of ways but can't seem to find the right syntax.

Thanks.

-Dan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure.
On change event find attribute in that element:

```
this.element.attr("data-id");
```

Example: [Get element attribute](https://dojo.telerik.com/UDacAmiR)

Comment: Nailed it in one!  Thanks.